# css 100% width background mask with access to slider beneath

Tags: css, mask

I have placed the following CSS div mask over an image slider.

```
<div class="contentMaskWrapper" >
    <div class="contentMaskLeft"></div>
    <div class="contentMaskRight"></div>
</div>
<div id="slider">
   slider content      
</div>

.contentMaskWrapper{
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
z-index:3;
height:564px;
    }
.contentMaskLeft{ 
background:url(../images/mask.png) repeat;
height:564px;
width:100%;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
margin-left:425px;
z-index:999;
}
.contentMaskRight{ 
background:url(../images/mask.png) repeat;
height:564px; 
width:100%; 
position:absolute; 
right:50%; 
margin-right:425px; 
z-index:999;
}
#slider{ 
width:850px; 
height:564px; 
margin:0 auto 20px; 
position:relative; 
clear:both; 
overflow:hidden; 
width:100%; }
```

The mask, which is displaying visually correct, sits either side of an image slider. The slider has a link and this link is only working in IE (7+), not FF, Safari or chrome (Mac or PC).

Hope this makes sense. Please let me know if you need more info. Appreciate any assistance.
Thanks,
Jamie

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously because both your masks are covering the link in your slider. (They have a higher z-index and the area only covered by the margin of each mask does count as covering too)

A solution could include absolute positioning without margins (left mask gets left: 0px; and right respectivly) or you could try to put your slider on top of the masks but only with the really needed size (which in your case is 425px*2 = 850px)

Answer (score 0):

as i noticed. your mask is overlapping your slidder. try to change the positioning of it by putting the slider above by making its z-index higher than the mask.